# Error inflating class on custom scrollview in XML?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, scrollview

I have an app that I am building using Mono Droid. I am trying to make an endless scrollview so that my users can scroll to the bottom and have more items loaded. Here is the class that I am using

```
public class EndlessScroll : ScrollView
{ 
    public EndlessScroll (Context context) : base (context)
    {}

    public EndlessScroll(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {}

    public EndlessScroll(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {}

    public interface OnScrollViewListener
    {
        void onScrollChanged(EndlessScroll v, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    public  OnScrollViewListener mOnScrollViewListener;

    public void setOnScrollViewListener(OnScrollViewListener l) 
    {
        this.mOnScrollViewListener = l;
    }

    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
    {
        mOnScrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        base.OnScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file. I converted all this code from Java so there may be something that I am doing wrong.

```
 <com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewDebug" />
</com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll>
```

Here is my error log

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll


at at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00068>
```

at Android.Runtime.JNIE nv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.18-series/3b7ef0a7/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896

at BirdsIView.getFromParse.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00016] in c:\Users\New User\Desktop\BirdsIView\BirdsIView\BirdsIView\getFromParse.cs:40
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.18-series/3b7ef0a7/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2179
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.06c20e74-6eec-438c-a399-394abf9bcd74 (intptr,intptr,intptr) 
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll

at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work. Apparently you need to name the xml like so

```
<BirdsIView.EndlessScroll
```

instead of

```
<com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just need to change these functions simple**

```
 public EndlessScroll (Context context) 
    {
       super(context);
        init();
    }

    public EndlessScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {

        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public EndlessScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
```

Comment: Android.Views.InflateException has been thrown. binary xml file line #1: error inflating class com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll

Comment: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll
  at at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00068>
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.18-series/3b7ef0a7/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896

Comment: End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.BirdsIView.BirdsIView.EndlessScroll

Comment: It wont let me copy and paste the whole thing. Its too long

Comment: I will add it in the details of the question

Comment: I have included it now

Comment: Thank you but I am using monodroid which is c#. I am trying to do the same thing you are in c#.

Comment: but just call these init methods

Comment: What would be the c# equivalent of init()?

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. What can I use in place of init()? That is not available to me.

Comment: you need to know what is the initilizer in your development envirment for views